# What is the braking power generated by an air brake system on a heavy truck?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction, power

Can't really find good resources on the Web. So what is the braking power generated by an air brake system on an average heavy truck/lorry ? Assuming let's say it's going from 100 km/h to a full stop.

A system like:

[image]

Would also be nice to know something more about the braking characteristics, e.g. the distribution of stopping power from start to finish. Thanks!

Comment: Brakes with some braking parameters should theoretically manifest those parameters irregardless of the type of braking system used. In other words: the necessary braking power shouldn't be dependent on the brakes using air or not.

Comment: Fair point. This was more about in relation to how the breaking power is actually distributed in time. I'm guessing each break system will have it's own set of characteristics.

Comment: I'm not an expert on these systems particularly, however i feel that pneumatic system would distribute the load more evenly due to air being compressible, but hydraulic system would act slightly faster due to having higher speed of sound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a useful way to get an *estimate*.

A sizeable truck will have a 400HP engine in it. If the braking system was capable of dissipating 400HP, then the truck could decelerate as fast as it accelerated. But in practice, you want the deceleration to happen perhaps 5 times faster than the acceleration, which means the braking system would have a rating of at least 2000HP- for a single stop, after which the brakes would be very hot indeed.